# how to send array data from java script to flask

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ajax, flask

how to send array from javascript to python flask.
the ajax is not returning the array (values)to flask route .Can anyone please help with these error

```
#flask route
@app.route('/admin',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def admin():
    if request.method == "POST":
        a=request.form.getlist("contacts[]")
        return str(a)
#js code
window.onload = function(){}
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.onclick = function(){
    var div= document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = generateit();
    document.getElementById("box").appendChild(div);
}

function generateit()
{
 return "<input type='text' class='txt' placeholder='Enter party name' required>&nbsp<input type='text' class ='txt1' placeholder = 'Enter region' required>&nbsp<input type='text' class='txt2' placeholder='Enter name' required>&nbsp<button id ='btn' onclick='removeit(this);'>Remove</button>";
}

function removeit(btn)
{
    document.getElementById("box").removeChild(btn.parentNode);
}

values =[]
$.ajax({
    url:'{{url_for("admin")}}',
    type:'POST',
    data:{contacts:values},
    success:function(res){}
  });




}
```

Comment: At what point is it not working? Sending the values to the server? Receiving the values on the server? Processing the value on the server? Returning the response from the server?

Answer (score 0):

let assume that your html code is like this:

```
<butoon id="generate_row">generate row</butoon>
<div id="box">
    <button onclick="send()">send</button>
</div>
```

here is your javascript code:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var btn = document.querySelector("#generate_row");
        var box = document.getElementById("box");

        btn.onclick = function () {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var row_num = box.querySelectorAll("#box > div").length + 1;  // add 1 to start from 1
            div.innerHTML = generateit(row_num);
            box.appendChild(div);
        }
    }

    function generateit(row_num) {
        return `<input type='text' placeholder='Enter party name' required>
                <input type='text' placeholder = 'Enter region' required>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Enter name' required>
                <button id ='btn_remove${row_num}' onclick='removeit(this);'>Remove</button>`;
    }

    function removeit(btn) {
        document.getElementById("box").removeChild(btn.parentNode);
    }

    function send() {
        values = [];
        let divs = document.querySelectorAll("#box > div");

        divs.forEach(innerDiv => {
            let innerDivValues = [];
            let textInputs = innerDiv.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
            textInputs.forEach(inputElement => innerDivValues.push(inputElement.value))
            values.push(innerDivValues);
        });
       
        
        fetch('{{url_for("site_bp.formit")}}', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({contacts: values})
        }).then(async response => await response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    }
```

and your flask route:

```
@bp.route('/formit',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def formit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        contacts=request.json.get("contacts", None)
        for contact in contacts:
            print (contact)
        return {"contacts": contacts}
    return "not post request"
```

i used blueprints so don't be confused about that @bp or site_bp.formit

Comment: getting no post request